# Is it right to say "I was annoyed about commuting ..."?

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, complementation

Is it right to say:

> Yesterday I was annoyed about commuting to my work because of a big traffic jam.

Answer (score 2):

I think the expression "annoyed about X" generally means that X is the root cause of the annoyance.

In this case, it sounds like weren't annoyed about commuting, but you were annoyed about the traffic jam.

If yesterday's traffic was unusually heavy and slow, then it might be better to say:

> Yesterday, I was annoyed by the traffic during my commute.

But if the heavy traffic happens almost every day, then you could say:

> I am annoyed by commuting because I don't like the heavy traffic.

---

As a footnote, the prepositions *by, about, with*, and *over* can all be used with the word *annoyed*, though [***by*** and ***with***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=annoyed%20by%2Cannoyed%20about%2C%20annoyed%20over&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15) seem to be the most common.

Comment: +1. There's also "annoyed *with*", IMHO. I wonder if "Yesterday I was annoyed commuting to my work because of a big traffic jam." would be okay (without a preposition, with "commuting to my work" serving in the sense of "while commuting to my work")

Comment: @CopperK - Yes, you're right about "annoyed with" – I've just amended my answer. And I also agree, you can omit the preposition, or use _while_. You can even change _commuting_ to _commute_: _Yesterday, I had an annoying commute because of a big traffic jam_ (or, _Yesterday's commute was annoying; the traffic was terrible_).